# Websocket event is being catched only by one component

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket, rxjs, observable

I have a websocket service in Angular7

```
import { environment } from './../../../environments/environment.prod';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
@Injectable()
export class WsService{
public wsMessages: Rx.Subject<any>;

public connect(url): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
    if(!this.subject){
        this.subject = this.create(url);
        console.log("Websocket (Dashboard) successfully connected to : ", url);
    } 
    return this.subject;
}

private create(url): Rx.Subject<MessageEvent> {
    let ws = new WebSocket(
        url,
        [`Bearer`, `${this.token.substring(7)}`] 
        );
    let observable = Rx.Observable.create(
        (obs: Rx.Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
            ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
            ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
            ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
            return ws.close.bind(ws);
        }
    )

    let observer = {
        next: (data: Object) => {
            if(ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                ws.send(JSON.stringify(data));
            }
        }
    }

    return Rx.Subject.create(observer, observable);
}
private token: string;
constructor(){
   this.token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).token
    this.wsMessages = <Rx.Subject<any>>
    this.connect(`${environment.websocketUrl}/dashboard/ws`)
    .pipe(
        map((response: MessageEvent): any =>{
            let data = JSON.parse(response.data);
            return data;
        })
    )
}
private subject: Rx.Subject<MessageEvent>;
```

}

and i have mulltiple component that subscribe to `wsMessages`

```
 this.ws.wsMessages.subscribe(msg => {
    this.catchWebSocketEvents(msg)
    console.log("LeftBarSocket : ", msg);
  })
```

the events are only printed on one component only and i need many components to listen to those ws events.

Comment: May be the other components are already `destroyed` by that time. Also, I would suggest you to use `BehaviorSubject` for such features as it retains the previous data, the `subject` looses the data once emitted (check if that could be your case)

Comment: the components are not destroyed, it has something to do with multicast maybe but i don't understand how to use it really.

Comment: I don't see where wsMessages get assigned a value?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after doing a bit of reading on the subject, I found out there is a `share()` function that allows multiple subscribers sharing a source.

the solution is here :

```
 const observable = Rx.Observable.create(
        (obs: Rx.Observer<MessageEvent>) => {
            this.ws.onmessage = obs.next.bind(obs);
            this.ws.onerror = obs.error.bind(obs);
            this.ws.onclose = obs.complete.bind(obs);
            return this.ws.close.bind(this.ws);
        }
    ).pipe(
        share()
    )
```

just need to add the `.pipe(share())` to the observable, being created.